# Get value of nested array from json

Tags: laravel

I have some JSON data which get from an API. I need only the products name from there. How can I get this?  I am already trying with foreach loop but I can't. I am using laravel framework version 6.0

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bijj",
    "categories": [
                {
                  "id": 10,
                  "name": "Rice",
                  "sbu": 2,
                  "products" : [
                     {
                        "id": 25,
                        "name": "Rajkumar",
                        "skus": [],
                        "short_description": "বাংলাদেশের আবহাওয়া উপযোগী হাইব্রিড ধান",
                     },
                     {
                        "id": 50,
                        "name": "Sera",
                        "skus": [],
                        "short_description": "বাংলাদেশের আবহাওয়া উপযোগী হাইব্রিড ধান",
                     }

                  ]
               },
               {
                 "id": 20,
                 "name": "Vhutta",
                 "sbu": 2,
                  "products" : [
                     {
                         "id": 129,
                         "name": "Pack-139",
                         "skus": [],
                         "short_description": "মোচায় ৮৬ % দানা ও ১৪ % শাঁস",
                     },
                     {
                        "id": 125,
                        "name": "Don-12",
                        "skus": [],
                        "short_description": "সারা বৎসর চাষ উপযোগী",
                     }   
                  ]
                }
       ]
  }
]
```

I want to get only the all products name form there.

```
$getSbu = Helper::CreateGuzzleHttpClient('sbu');
foreach ($getSbu as  $value) {
     if($value->id == 2) {
          foreach ($value->categories as $category) {
                $products = $category->products;
             }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Share your code and explain what you have tried and what problems you are facing in that code

Comment: I am edited my post.

Comment: That's not json, not array.  Before `"id"`, it still need a `"{"`

Comment: sorry, I missed that. correction done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want get only product's name ??

and if your data **array** then you have to change **$value['id']**

```
$product_names = [];
foreach ($getSbu as  $value) {
     if($value->id == 2) {
          foreach ($value->categories as $category) {
                foreach ($category->products as $product) {
                     $product_names[] = $product->name;
                }
          }
      }
}
dd($product_names);
```

Answer (score 2):

After decode you can simply use this helper

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Arr::only($array, ['categories.products.name']);
or 
Arr::only($array, ['categories.*.name']);
```

Comment: This will be not working, because there are array inside.

Comment: `$getSbu = Helper::CreateGuzzleHttpClient('sbu');
$name = Arr::only($getSbu, ['categories.products.name']);
 dd($name);`

get empty array

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (json_decode($getSbu) as  $value) {
```

Foreach works in an array so first you must decode it in order to parse it as an array.

Since you use `object` parsing you don't have to use parameter `true` in your json_decode function. If you want an array instead of an object you can use:

```
foreach (json_decode($getSbu,true) as  $value) {
```

but then you access your value like array fields, for example `value['id']`

Your code should look like:

```
$getSbu = Helper::CreateGuzzleHttpClient('sbu');
foreach (json_decode($getSbu) as  $value) {
     if($value->id == 2) {
          foreach ($value->categories as $category) {
                $products = $category->products;
             }
           }
        }
```

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Show this error.

Comment: Based on your question $getSbu is a json. Your error says that it is already an array

Answer (score 0):

Leverage aravel collections

```
// this is just ur data but as json string
$var = '[{"id":2,"name":"Bijj","categories":[{"id":10,"name":"Rice","sbu":2,"products":[{"id":25,"name":"Rajkumar","skus":[],"short_description":"বাংলাদেশের আবহাওয়া উপযোগী হাইব্রিড ধান"},{"id":50,"name":"Sera","skus":[],"short_description":"বাংলাদেশের আবহাওয়া উপযোগী হাইব্রিড ধান"}]},{"id":20,"name":"Vhutta","sbu":2,"products":[{"id":129,"name":"Pack-139","skus":[],"short_description":"মোচায় ৮৬ % দানা ও ১৪ % শাঁস"},{"id":125,"name":"Don-12","skus":[],"short_description":"সারা বৎসর চাষ উপযোগী"}]}]}]';

$objCollection = collect(json_decode($var, true));

$productNames = $objCollection->pluck('categories.*.products.*.name');

dd($productNames);
```

Comment: This will be not working to this question. because the `products` inside is still array. you still need to loop it.

Comment: @TsaiKoga now it does work for sure, you just add a * for that.